# PrismaClientInitializationError: Query engine library for current platform "linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x" could not be found

Tags: docker, prisma

Prisma Client was built on a different platform than the one it is being run on.

I'm using an m1 mac and my docker image is node:19-alpine.

when I do prisma -v on my mac I get this config:

```
prisma                  : 4.13.0
@prisma/client          : 4.13.0
Current platform        : darwin-arm64
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine 1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-darwin-arm64.dylib.node)
Migration Engine        : migration-engine-cli 1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-darwin-arm64)
Format Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-fmt-wasm 4.13.0-50.1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a
Default Engines Hash    : 1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a
Studio                  : 0.484.0
```

When I do prisma -v in my node:19-alpine container I get this:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                  : 4.13.0
@prisma/client          : 4.13.0
Current platform        : linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine 1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x.so.node)
Migration Engine        : migration-engine-cli 1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x)
Format Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-fmt-wasm 4.13.0-50.1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a
Default Engines Hash    : 1e7af066ee9cb95cf3a403c78d9aab3e6b04f37a
Studio                  : 0.484.0
```

I tried configuring my schema.prisma to:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native","darwin", "darwin-arm64"]
}
```

But I am still getting erros. Below is the error I got:

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Query engine library for current platform "linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x" could not be found.
You incorrectly pinned it to linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x

This probably happens, because you built Prisma Client on a different platform.
(Prisma Client looked in "/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/libquery_engine-linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x.so.node")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as you and found this to be the solution.

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets   = ["native", "linux-musl-arm64-openssl-3.0.x"]
}
```

If this doesn't solve your issue I would suggest looking in this section of the documentation:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/generators#binary-targets